# Windows Terminal script execution with keybinds

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal

Is it possible in the Windows Terminal to bind Keys to execute a certain command? for example:
"alt+c" for "code ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v1.1.2021.0, you cannot do it at the level of Windows Terminal itself (it only allows you to execute a command in the context of creating *a new tab* - see [Custom key bindings in Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/key-bindings)).

However, you can do it via the [`PSReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline) module that ships with PowerShell:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler 'alt+c' -ScriptBlock {
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert('code .')
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AcceptLine()
}
```

If you place the above in your `$PROFILE` file, the key binding will be available in future session.